Error while digitally signing on multiple pages in a PDF using Python endesive
I'm trying to digitally sign the PDF document using Class 3 USB token by searching a specific text 'Authorised Signatory' in the page, it works perfectly fine when I have to sign a PDF once. But in one scenario I came across multiple page document and in which I have to sign each page, after signing the PDF when I tried to validate the signatures in the Adobe PDF Reader it has only validated my first signature as shown in the below screenshot

And I was not able to see the annotations of the second and third page.
Here is my code,
def post(self, request):
        serializer = PDFSignSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            data = serializer.validated_data.get('pdf_base64')

            try:
                pdf_data = base64.b64decode(data)
            except Exception as e:
                return Response({'error': f'Failed to decode base64 PDF data: {e}'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            # Search for text in the PDF and retrieve coordinates
            text_to_find = 'Authorised Signatory'  # Text to search for (modify as needed)
            text_positions = self.find_text_in_pdf(pdf_data, text_to_find)

            if not text_positions:
                return Response({'error': 'No position found for signature'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            # Get the current UTC time using timezone-aware objects
            current_utc_time = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)

            # Calculate the Indian time by adding the UTC offset of +5:30
            indian_time = current_utc_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)

            # Format the Indian time string in 24-hour format
            indian_time_str = indian_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + ' UTC+5:30'

            # Initialize the signer
            #In above code the settings.DLLPATH is the path of the file - eps2003csp11v2.dll in windows OS
            clshsm = Signer(settings.DLLPATH)  # Adjust this according to your settings

            # Prepare signing data structure
            date = indian_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=11)
            date = date.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S+00\'00\'')
            dct = {
                "sigflags": 3,
                "sigbutton": True,
                "contact": f'Digitally signed\nDate: {indian_time_str}',
                "location": 'India',
                "signingdate": date.encode(),
                "reason": 'Approved',
                "text": {
                    'wraptext': True,
                    'fontsize': 6,
                    'textalign': 'left',
                    'linespacing': 1,
                },
                "signature_appearance": {
                    'background': r'C:\Users\Guest\Downloads\check_mark.png',
                    'labels': False,
                    'display': 'contact'.split(','),
                },
            }

            for position in text_positions:
                try:
                    # Reload the PDF document to avoid xref table issues
                    signed_pdf_data = pdf_data
                    
                    dct["sigpage"] = position['page_number']
                    dct["signaturebox"] = (
                        position['x0'] - 10,
                        position['page_height'] - position['y0'],
                        position['x1'] + 10,
                        position['page_height'] - position['y0'] + 60
                    )

                    signed_pdf_data = pdf.cms.sign(signed_pdf_data, dct, None, None, [], 'sha256', clshsm)
                    pdf_data = pdf_data + signed_pdf_data
                    # Return the signed PDF data after each signing operation
                    
                    print(base64.b64encode(pdf_data).decode())
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    return Response({'error': f'Failed to sign at position {position}: {e}'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            # Prepare response
            response_data = {
                        'message': 'PDF signed successfully.',
                        'signed_pdf_base64': base64.b64encode(pdf_data).decode()
                    }
            return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

additionally the signer class code as follows:
class Signer(hsm.HSM):
    def certificate(self):
        self.login("Token", "password")
        keyid = [0x5e, 0x9a, 0x33, 0x44, 0x8b, 0xc3, 0xa1, 0x35, 0x33, 0xc7, 0xc2, 0x02, 0xf6, 0x9b, 0xde, 0x55, 0xfe, 0x83, 0x7b, 0xde]
        keyid = bytes(keyid)
        try:
            pk11objects = self.session.findObjects([(PK11.CKA_CLASS, PK11.CKO_CERTIFICATE)])
            all_attributes = [
                PK11.CKA_VALUE,
                PK11.CKA_ID,
            ]

            for pk11object in pk11objects:
                try:
                    attributes = self.session.getAttributeValue(pk11object, all_attributes)
                except PK11.PyKCS11Error as e:
                    continue

                attrDict = dict(list(zip(all_attributes, attributes)))
                cert = bytes(attrDict[PK11.CKA_VALUE])
                return bytes(attrDict[PK11.CKA_ID]), cert
        finally:
            self.logout()
        return None, None

    def sign(self, keyid, data, mech):
        self.login("Token", "password")
        try:
            privKey = self.session.findObjects([(PK11.CKA_CLASS, PK11.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY)])[0]
            mech = getattr(PK11, 'CKM_%s_RSA_PKCS' % mech.upper())
            sig = self.session.sign(privKey, data, PK11.Mechanism(mech, None))
            return bytes(sig)
        finally:
            self.logout()

Where am I making a mistake?

I'm not a endesive user, and I don't understand the part:
                    # Reload the PDF document to avoid xref table issues
                    signed_pdf_data = pdf_data

Each signature adds a new PDF version to a PDF file.
I think that pdf_data is not reread, so the second signature, which should sign the second PDF version, signs only the data of the first PDF version.
Reading the endesive source code it seems that it adds an "pdf annotation" using the line:
    if box is not None:
        self.addAnnotation(cert, udct, box, page0ref, obj13, obj13ref, new_13)

An annotation is something visual that is appended to a PDF file and shown by PDF readers, overlaying original pages with it.
It would be nice if endesive could create several annotations per signature (several boxes), then you only had to sign once, but it seems that it can't. You could try to add several annotations by hand.
If you the one signature per page approach, you would have to start the signature process each time (rereading the new PDF).
